# The method putDoublArray(String, double[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Double[])

Tags: android, bundle

How to resolve this fault . And how to get data of array from 'for(Blog blog:blogList)' . 
Can you tell me ,which fault in my code ?
//The method putDoubleArray(String, double[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Double[])

```
final ArrayList<Blog> blogList = (ArrayList<Blog>) message
                .getResultList("Blog");
        for (Blog blog : blogList) {
            int i=0;
                latitude_Array[i] = Double.parseDouble(blog.getLatitude_zzs());
                longitude_Array[i]=Double.parseDouble(blog.getLongitude_zzs());
                i++;
        }
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_top_map_list);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity_MapList.class);
                    //The method putDoubleArray(String, double[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Double[])
                    bundle.putDoubleArray("latitude_Array", latitude_Array);

                    // intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just what the error message says. Evidently, your `latitude_Array` variable is declared to be `Double []`. One fix is to declare your `latitude_Array` (and probably also `longitude_Array` to be of type `double []` instead of `Double []`. (Case, as always, is significant. A `Double` is an object that holds a primitive `double` value. It's main use is for collections, that cannot hold primitives.)

If you absolutely need them to be of type `Double []`, then you'll have to copy the values over to a primitive array before stuffing it into a `Bundle`.

Comment: Although there is a method `Bundle.putIntegerArrayList(String key, ArrayList<Integer> value)`, there is no equivalent method to deal with `ArrayList<Double>`.

Comment: How to copy the latitude from 'for(Blog blog:blogList)' to latitude_Array. I use  the  interrupted point ,  at'latitude_Array[i]' goto catch.

Comment: @jpa2012 - `Double.parseDouble(String)` returns a primitive `double` value. If you declare your `latitude_Array` to be of type `double[]`, then the code you posted should not have to change at all. (Currently, it is autoboxing the primitive `double` into a `Double`.)

Comment: @jpa2012 - Just change the declaration `Double [] latitude_Array` to `double [] latitude_Array`.